# Finding Number of Element of Each Column in 2-d Array

Tags: c

I try to make C program but get problem.
The program is finding number of elements in each column.

Input :

```
4 4
```

Matrix:

```
1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1
```

Output should be the number of 1's in columns

Output :

```
2 1 2 3
```

This my program but it does not work properly:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i , j, r , c , n , a[100][100],max[100];
    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&r);
    printf("Enter the number of columns: ");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    printf("Enter the elements of the array- \n");

    printf("The input matrix is:- \n");
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        max[i] = a[i][j];
        for(j = 0; j < c ; j++)
        {
            if(a[i][j]>max[i])
            {
                max[i]=a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        printf("the element of the row %d is: %d\n",i,max[i]);
    }
}
```

I need help for fixed the program. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
max[i] = a[i][j];
for(j = 0; j < c ; j++)
```

with

```
max[i] = a[i][0];
for(j = 1; j < c ; j++)
```

Otherwise you store the value `a[i][c]` as `max` on each iteration and that's not what you want.

Also, you are not filling the array, you can use some random value to test your program:

```
...
#include <time.h>
...

int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    ...

    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = rand();
            printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Edit:

`max` is not a good name if you want to count the number of `1`'s.

and

```
printf("the element of the row %d is: %d\n",i,max[i]);
```

should be

```
printf("Number of 1's in row %d is: %d\n",i,max[i]);
```

Please, do an effort explaining the problem next time.

Your code working with randoms, just adapt it to `scanf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i , j, r = 5, c = 10, n , a[100][100],max[100];

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    printf("The input matrix is:- \n");
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = rand() & 1;
            printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        max[i] = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < c ; j++)
        {
            if(a[i][j] == 1)
            {
                max[i]++;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        printf("Number of 1's in row %d is: %d\n",i,max[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223932/discussion-on-answer-by-david-ranieri-finding-number-of-element-of-each-column-i).